# Java method not returning output?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner, dice

I created 3 different methods. I am assuming the first one used will not return and output but there is a possibility all of them aren't. I don't understand why. This is a large chunk of code I know but I wanted to add the whole thing because I am not sure what is causing this to happen. When I run the program it does not print anything to the screen and never stops running.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int currentPool = 100;
    while (currentPool > 0);{
        int bet = getBet(in, currentPool);
        if (bet == 0){
            System.out.println("You have " + currentPool + " dollars left.");
            System.out.println("goodbye!");
            currentPool = 0;
        }
        else{
            char highLow = getHighLow(in);
            int roll = getRoll();
            int winnings = determineWinnings(highLow, bet, roll);
            currentPool = currentPool + winnings;
        }
    }

}

private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int currentPool) {
    System.out.println("You have " + currentPool + " dollars.");
    System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
    int bet = inScanner.nextInt();
    while (bet > currentPool || bet < 0){
        System.out.println("Your bet MUST be between 0 and " + currentPool + " dollars.");
        System.out.println("You have " + currentPool + " dollars.");
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
        bet = inScanner.nextInt();
    }
    return bet;     
}

private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.println("High, Low, or Sevens (H/L/S): ");
    String highLowSevens = inScanner.nextLine();
    highLowSevens = highLowSevens.toUpperCase();
    while (!highLowSevens.equals("H") && !highLowSevens.equals("L") && !highLowSevens.equals("S")){
        System.out.println("That is not one of the options!");
        System.out.println("High, Low, or Sevens (H/L/S): ");
        highLowSevens = inScanner.nextLine();
    }
        char hLS = highLowSevens.charAt(0);
        return hLS;

}

private static int getRoll() {
    int roll = (int)(6 * Math.random() + 1);
    return roll;
}

private static int determineWinnings(char highLow, int bet, int roll) {
    if (((highLow == 'H') && (roll > 7)) || ((highLow == 'L') && (roll < 7))){
        return bet; 
    }
    else{
        if (((highLow == 'S') && (roll == 7))){
            return (bet*4);
        }
        else{
            return (bet*(-1));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
while (currentPool > 0);
```

To

```
while (currentPool > 0)
```

In your main method.

Comment: The semicolon is causing an infiinite loop.